# Beamer: Put an Updating Outline/TOC on Every Slide

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, presentations

I'm looking to be able to have an outline or table of contents on the side of every slide fairly automatically, though it would be good if it could be suppressed on some slides. This outline would update as the presentation progresses, showing which point have already been covered.

I would prefer a less obtrusive way of indicating the state of the presentation, but this is an external requirement.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you mind providing some more info? It would be useful to know if you are using a sidebar theme or you are designing your own theme. Best would be if you could sketch a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to show us the general layout of your presentation and the specific place where you want the TOC.

Comment: like this? http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/all/beamer-default-Berkeley-1.png

Comment: Yes, something like that. I assume the level to which it prints the sections is configurable, and that the section names correspond to slides, or groups of slides?

Answer (score 1):

Beamer has several themes that provide this functionality automatically. One example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\section{First Section}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First frame}
Text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}
Text
\end{frame}



\section{Second Section}

\subsection{sub1}
\begin{frame}{Third frame}
Text
\end{frame}

\subsection{sub2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Fourth frame}
Text
\pause
more text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is of course highly customisable, as everything in latex. For example to only show sections `\usetheme[hideallsubsections]{Berkeley}`. See the `beameruserguide` section 15.4 for more options.